# Resolve Dependency on a repository interface MVC5 using structuremap

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap4

I have a mapper that takes data from a repository project. I have a IMenueMapper interface that is passed into the homecontroller like this:

```
public HomeController(IMenueMapper menueMapper)
{
    _menueMapper = menueMapper;
}
```

but the menuemapper class itself use the `IMenueMapperRepository`, and this come from another project and is passed in via dll

```
public MenueMapper(IMenueItemsRepository menueItems)
{
    _menueItems = menueItems;
}
```

While I can easily resolve the IMenuemapper in the MVC project, using structuremap.mvc5, I can't resolve the repository. Is there a way of achieving the DI in this instance?

Comment: Why don't you use `For ` also for the `IMenueItemsRepository`?  Something like this `For(typeof(IMenueItemsRepository)).Use(typeof(....))`, where `...` refers to a concrete implementation of `IMenueItemsRepository`.

Comment: You need to register the abstraction (repository interface and implementation) in the composition root.

Comment: @Nkosi What do you mean by that?

Comment: @JackM how was `IMenueMapper ` registered with structure map container?

Comment: in the DefaultRegistry I have  scan.AssemblyContainingType<MenueMapper>();

Comment: @Christos: where Would I put that? I tried using ////For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
            this.For<IMenueItemsRepository>().Use<MenueItemsRepository>(); in the defaultRegistry of the MVC project but I am getting an error that the IMenueItemsRepository is not bound

Comment: Can you do the same scan for `MenueItemsRepository`? You already stated it is in another assembly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135494/discussion-between-jack-m-and-nkosi).

Comment: @Nkosi: you are right, I needed to add the dependency in the MVC project I am not sure how to accept your answer though. Thanks very much.

Comment: @JackM, I compiled comments into an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the abstraction (repository interface and implementation) in the composition root.

You indicated that the `IMenueMapper` is registered via;

```
scan.AssemblyContainingType<MenueMapper>();
```

Since

> but the `MenueMapper` class itself use the `IMenueMapperRepository`, and
>   this come from another project and is passed in via dll

Then it should also be scanned as it belongs to another assembly

```
scan.AssemblyContainingType<MenueItemsRepository>();
```

Make sure that the project references the assembly in question